# How to extract a data from soap (XML) response in Jmeter for next request body

Tags: soap, jmeter

**I couldn't parse the SessionID from this response in Jmeter 5.5.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please [don't post code as the image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), otherwise your question will be either ignored or you will get a generic answer like the one below:

You need to handle [XML namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) somehow.

Given you have the following XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

   <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:m = "http://www.example.com/quotation">
      <m:GetQuotationResponse>
         <m:Quotation>Here is the quotation</m:Quotation>
      </m:GetQuotationResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and want to extract `Here is the quotation`

The options are in:

1. Use [local-name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name) function:

   [image]
2. Or go for [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) and specify all the namespaces there:

   [image]

More information: [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: here is the response body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetSessionExtendResponse
   xmlns="http://bracbank.com">
   <GetSessionExtendResult>
    <StatusCode>000</StatusCode>
    <StatusDescription>Success</StatusDescription>
    <SessionID>674ae217-e70e-4ceb-8dd7-3777b6e116f3</SessionID>
   </GetSessionExtendResult>
  </GetSessionExtendResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: I couldn't parse yet the SessionID, could please suggest me the expression??
I've tried following these- //Body/GetSessionExtendResponse/GetSessionExtendResult/SessionID/text()
//SessionID/text()

Comment: Have you tried to read and understand my response? If you prefer to copy and paste - here is the expression: `//*[local-name()='SessionID']/text()` however I would rather recommend using XPath2 Extractor, here is a demo using [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2xDV.png